# Java: Adding JAR files to the class path of another Jar file

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have a Jar(suppose jar1) file which needs few other jar files(Present in the same directory suppose myjar1.jar and myjar2.jar and so on) during the runtime. I am not able to do that  using manifest file. I have added below

```
   Class-Path: myjar1.jar
```

and also

```
      Class-Path: ./*
```

I am creating the Jar(jar1) in my local and pushing it to the server. During compilation and building the Jar(jar1) I dont know the jars(and I dont need them for compilation) that I have to add to the class path. Once I copy it to the server I want other jars present in that directory to be in the class path of my Jar(jar1).

**PS**  I have read almost all the articles about adding the classpath to Jar and I am aware that we cannot add classpath as part of the arguments.

I have total control of the manifest file while compiling and building the Jar.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include all the dependent JAR files in your manifest file as below. Use blank space as a separator.

```
Class-Path: lib/myjar1.jar lib/myjar2.jar
```

After building your JAR file, extract the JAR and check whether the manifest file is created properly.

Comment: I have tried that as mentione in my question but its not working

Comment: Are you sure that you have added all the dependent JARs in a space separated way? Did you check the manifest file inside the JAR file after building it? If you have the correct manifest file in the JAR and all the dependent JARs are copied into the same directory where your JAR is placed, things should work as expected.

Comment: It does not load the specified Jars during runtime.

Comment: Thank you  @Loganathan Mohanraj .So you say that the JAR's would be added to the classpath during runtime

Comment: I tried that and I could see the  the othe Jar names in class-path of manifest file, but during run time the jars are not being referenced. did I miss anything?

Comment: Did you copy all the JAR files into the classpath?

Comment: All the other Jars are present in the same directory where my Jar is located

Comment: Interesting! Check the file permissions set for the dependent JAR files. In a worst case, set executable permissions for all the dependent JARs and then try (ideally read permission is enough).